# Catching an exception during a transaction and saving the error to DB, but modified entities in try block also getting saved

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-transactions

Below is the code I have implemented:

```
@Transactional
MethodA{
  try{
     fetch from DB, update entities and save them;
     some exception occurs;
  } catch(Exception e){
     update Exception to DB;
  }
}
```

The updates I do to the entities in the try block are also saved to DB. How to circumvent this?

Comment: Your code is wrong, due to you catching an exception Spring doesn't know it needs to rollback. So eother do the exception handling outside of `methodA` or do manual tx management so that both your regular code and error handling code use a different transaction.

Comment: You are catching exception, Spring will rollback any RuntimeException, in your code there will be no exceptions thrown. So you should not catch the exception, or rethrow it, but remembering that it should extend RuntimeException

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.